# Wrapper function in decorator

Tags: python, function, class, decorator, wrapper

I need to have a wrapper function here but I do not really know **what the wrapper function does here**, honestly I tried to find the answer on the internet, before I ask but I couldn't so I'd appreciate it if you explain it to me with an example.

```
def decorate_it(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("Before function call")
        func()
        print("After function call")
    return wrapper

def hello():
    print("Hello world")

hello = decorate_it(hello)

hello()
# Prints Before function call
# Prints Hello world
# Prints After function call
```

I mean what is the problem that I get a `TypeError` when I use this code below:

```
def decorate_it(func):
    print("Before function call")
    func()
    print("After function call")

def hello():
    print("Hello world")

hello = decorate_it(hello)

hello()
```

Comment: In your second example, function `decorate_it()` returns `None`, so you are assigning `None` to variable `hello` and then call it. That results in error.

Comment: Highly recommended, learn everything about it here: https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/

Comment: in second example `decorate_it()` runs `help()` at once - it doesn't create function (wrapper) which you can `return` and run later. If you run `decorate_it(hello)` even without `hello = ...` then you will see all strings at once and you don't need to run later `hello()`

Comment: in first example `decorate_it()` doesn't runs `help()` at once but it returns new function (wrapper)` which you can run later. If you run `decorate_it(hello)` without next `hello()` then you don't see strings.